# security risk in sessions when Login

Tags: php, session, authentication

When I login in to my admin panel I define a session e.g. $_SESSION['admin'].
in admin panel I have this code:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['admin'])){
   header("Location: ../index.php");
   die();
}
```

When you login the session will be created and you can access admin panel. but there is a problem in this:
I have created another php file and put this codes on it:

```
<?php
$_SESSION['admin'] = 1;
header("Location: adminpanel/index.php");
die();
?>
```

When I run this file I can go to admin panel without login to it and no need to username and password. It means that if anybody know my sessions can login to panels. 
what should I do? What is the correct way for login? or how to solve this problem?

Comment: Of course you can go to the admin-panel if you visit the other file - you set the session there.

Answer (score 1):

so basically you dont want anyone to access the file that sets your `session` for confirmation of login. Lets assume this file is named `login.php`. One easy way to avoid people from accessing it is to deny access to it if the `conditions` are not met.

```
if(login conditions met){
    //set session for confirmed login
    $_SESSION['admin'] = 1;
    //redirect to where you want
} else {
    //conditions not met
    $_SESSION['admin'] = 0;
    //redirect to error page
}
```

apart from that, make sure you set correct file permissions on your server side

Comment: This is the right answer. The login status of the user has to be checked on every single page that is considered walled off—using things like JWT can help to authenticate users.

Answer (score 0):

Session data is kept on the server and its unique for every user. This is negotiated between the browser and the server automatically. While there are ways to highjack a session - https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack - most modern servers and server-side technologies implement protections out of the box.

In your case, you don't hijack the session, you just artificially log in because you have access to the server and can put the second file there, which an attacker cannot do. If an attacker gains write access to your server, logging into your admin panel is the least of your problems.

Bottom line: there's no security vulnerability in the code you described. How to test properly: upload the code to a server and try to get in without putting another file on that server.

Comment: i think his question was more about 'someone can directly go to his script and set login sessions without going through the login form', if I am not mistaken.

Comment: in my projects I usually use $_SESSION['user'] and $_SESSION['admin'].

Comment: my question is this: if anybody create a page like I created and upload it on some where else not in my host and run that page, can he access to my panels? for examples I create a session and then use header like this: header("location: www.mysite.com/usercp"); . before this session is defined. Is this possible?

Comment: No! Sessions are not shared between different servers or different domains.